# Laravel S3 file upload test errors

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a test to mock an S3 upload which generates a pre-signed url.

Here is my test:

```
    public function test_it_uploads_to_s3()
    {
        Storage::fake('s3');

        $response = $this->json('POST', route('api.presignedUpload', 1), [
            'name' => 'file.txt',
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonStructure(['url']);
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:
`Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local::getClient()`

I thought I only needed to add the `Storage::fake('s3');` part and it should mock S3 or am I mistaken?

Edit:
The controller function code:

```
 $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
 $client = $s3->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();

 $cmd = $client->getCommand('PutObject', [
     'Bucket' => \Config::get('s3.bucket'),
     'Key' => 'files/' . $request->name,
     'ACL' => 'private',
 ]);

 $request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $this->expiry);

 $presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();

 return response()->json(['url' => $presignedUrl], 201);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the error you're getting with only this context but it seems that you're missing some code according to the [Laravel 8.x docs for this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#storage-fake):

```php
public function test_it_uploads_to_s3() {

    Storage::fake('s3');

    $response = $this->json('POST', route('api.presignedUpload', 1), [
        UploadedFile::fake()->file('file.txt')
    ]);

    Storage::disk('s3')->assertExists('file.txt');

    $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonStructure(['url']);

}
```

Comment: Is this testing the file actually uploads to S3? All I want is to create a pre-signed url, so that the file can be uploaded later, but maybe it's similar?

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood your question but I believe what you're looking for is explained in this [post](https://beckermanyaakov.medium.com/uploading-files-directly-to-s3-digital-ocean-with-laravel-9efc30eb44c8)

Comment: You were mroe right the first time :-) I've implemented pre-signed url creation, and I want to test it generates a pre-signed url.

In other words I want to test the method you sent in your link.

Comment: @reans I am in the same position as you were. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Digvijay No I wasn't really. I simply resorted to writing tests for a real S3 bucket.

Comment: @reans I was able to figure this one out. If you could share the function where the presigned uri is generated, I can help you with the mocking part.

Comment: @Digvijay thanks, I've added the code to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the filesystem and test this out.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Mockery;

protected static function mockPresignedUrl()
{
    $storage = Mockery::mock('League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local');

    $storage->shouldReceive('getAdapter')->andReturn($storage)
        ->shouldReceive('getClient')->andReturn($storage)
        ->shouldReceive('getBucket')->andReturn('s3')
        ->shouldReceive('getCommand')->andReturn($storage)
        ->shouldReceive('createPresignedRequest')->andReturn($storage)
        ->shouldReceive('getUri')->andReturn('https://some-presigned-url');

    return $storage;
}


public function test_it_uploads_to_s3()
{
    $storage = $this->mockPresignedUrl();
    
    Storage::set('s3', $storage);

    $this->putJson(route('api.presignedUpload', 1), [
            'name' => 'file.txt',
        ])
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson([
            'url' => 'https://some-presigned-url'
        ]);
}
```